# update image in directory with images of same directory

Tags: python, image-processing, google-colaboratory

i have  a  directory with  the set of images of different sizes ,let me show  you images  and their sizes

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
from PIL import Image
import glob
import time
from pylab import *
for filename in glob.iglob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/*.jpg'):
  print(filename)
```

results of this code is  :

```
/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/cat1.jpg
/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/cat2.jpg
/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/cat3.jpg
/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/cat4.jpg
/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/cat5.jpg
/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/cat6.jpg
/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/cat7.jpg
```

now let us consider  their sizes

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import time
from pylab import *
for filename in glob.iglob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/*.jpg'):
  im=array(Image.open(filename))
  print(im.shape)
```

result of this code is :

```
(410, 618, 3)
(1200, 1800, 3)
(576, 1024, 3)
(1533, 2300, 3)
(400, 600, 3)
(264, 191, 3)
(194, 259, 3)
```

of course i can convert it to the grayscale  using following line

```
im=array(Image.open(filename).convert('L'))
```

result :

```
(410, 618)
(1200, 1800)
(576, 1024)
(1533, 2300)
(400, 600)
(264, 191)
(194, 259)
```

as  you see different images have different size, what i want is to reshape  all images with the  same size(resize function exist for this one i know) and i want to update(replace) old image with the same image-so i have  , that all images in my directory should have same sizes, how can i do it? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was much easy, then i was  thinking about it, so here is my solution

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
from PIL import Image
import glob
import time
from pylab import *
#directory_name ='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/'
for filename in glob.iglob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/*.jpg'):
  #print(filename[-8:])
  im=(Image.open(filename).convert('L'))
  im=im.resize((100,100))
  #filename=filename[-8:]
  #complete_name =directory_name+filename
  print(complete_name)
  im.save(filename)
```

test  :

```
for filename in glob.iglob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cats/*.jpg'):
   im=array((Image.open(filename).convert('L')))
   print(im.shape)
```

result :

```
(100, 100)
(100, 100)
(100, 100)
(100, 100)
(100, 100)
(100, 100)
(100, 100)
```

Comment: Accepting your own answer is certainly [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in such situations.